# C#: An update query values not reflected in the intended oracle table

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I'm trying to update some records in an oracle table using c#. I don't get errors, but when I have looked at the records that I wanted to update, I've found out that the records still have the same old values. to see if each query was executed successfully, I have used this line `rowid= cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` which returns the number of affected rows by the query `19583`. The number that I have got is the number of rows in my table.

```
[OperationContract]

  public int pushData(string CustomObjects)
  {

      List<CustomObject> myDeserializedObjList = (List<CustomObject>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(CustomObjects, 
      typeof(List<CustomObject>));
      string constr = "my connection string";
      int rowid = 0;
      using(OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr)){

      con.Open();
      OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
      cmd.Connection = con;
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

       foreach (CustomObject element in myDeserializedObjList)
       {

          int num = element.num;

          string mydate = element.mydate;

          long num2 = element.num2;

          string user = element.user;


          string sqlStatement= "UPDATE CustomObjectS SET  num = num, 
          mydate=mydate, num2=num2, user=user  WHERE num = num";
          OracleTransaction myTrans;

          // Start a local transaction
          myTrans = con.BeginTransaction();
          // Assign transaction object for a pending local transaction
          cmd.Transaction = myTrans;
          cmd.CommandText=sqlStatement;
          cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("num", num));
          cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("user", user));
          cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("num2", num2));
          cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("mydate", OracleDbType.Date));
          cmd.Parameters[3].Value = mydate;


                  rowid= cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                  myTrans.Commit();



          }


     }


      return rowid;

  }
```

Comment: There are no bind variables in your DML string `"UPDATE CustomObjectS SET  num = num, mydate=mydate, num2=num2, user=user  WHERE num = num"`. Did you intend `"UPDATE CustomObjectS SET  num = :num, mydate=:mydate, num2=:num2, user=:user  WHERE num = :num"`? (and you don't need to set `num = :num` as they are equal in the where clause).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're updating rows with their current values. Try adding `:` to parameter names in the query:

```
UPDATE CustomObjectS SET  num = :num, 
          mydate=:mydate, num2=:num2, user=:user  WHERE num = :num
```

[Using Oracle parameters](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/articles/parameters.html)

Comment: Also, I'd avoid using exactly the same names for both columns and parameters (maybe add a prefix like "par"). And `cmd.Parameters[3].Value = mydate;` doesn't seem like a good idea: once you added another parameter, "mydate"'s index may change...  `cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("mydate", OracleDbType.Date)).Value = mydate;` may be a better way to do it.

Comment: Thank you it seems like we have solved a part of  the problem. Now, I'm getting this error `SoapFault - faultcode: 'a:InternalServiceFault' faultstring: 'ORA-1843: not a valid month' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@6c9cf70`

Comment: @s.e I would suggest to convert `string mydate = element.mydate;` to DateTime and pass that as a parameter. Something like `DateTime mydate = DateTime.ParseExact(element.mydate, "<date_format_here>", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`